# Calling private method from a static method

Tags: php, oop, php-5.3

I have an Error class that has public static method db_log_error() and  private method _log().

db_log_error() calls the _log() method.

When I try `$this->_log()` I get `PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context`

When I try  `self::_log()` I get `PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method Error::log() should not be called statically`

So what is the best approach for what I am trying to do?

Comment: I created an instance of the class within the static method, and it works, but it just seems unnecessarily complicated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most ideal solution: Make the `_log()` method static.

Or, disable strict standards:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the `log` method static as well, if it needs to be called from a static context.